# Copy listview1 to listview2

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy the checked item in ListADGroup and copy to ListADGroup2. ListADGroup updates with all the groups but when I try adding them to ListADGroup2 it copies the right amount checkboxes but they are empty. Im not sure what is missing from the button command to copy the data properly.

[image]

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Drawing"
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

Clear-Host

#== Create a New Form ==#
$TSTAPP=New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$TSTAPP.topmost=$true
$TSTAPP.Text="Test App"
$TSTAPP.Location.x=750
$TSTAPP.Location.Y=330
$TSTAPP.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,330)

#== Now Lock the form so it cannot be re-sized ==#
$TSTAPP.MaximumSize=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,330)
$TSTAPP.MinimumSize=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(750,330)

#== Group List Label ==#
$GroupL = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$GroupL.Text = "Select Group:"
$GroupL.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(4,5)
$GroupL.AutoSize = $true
$TSTAPP.Controls.Add($GroupL)

#== AD Users Listbox ==#
$ListADGroup = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Listview
$ListADGroup.Width = 356
$ListADGroup.height = 220
$ListADGroup.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(4,22)
#$ListADGroup.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$ListADGroup.CheckBoxes = $true
$ListADGroup.Name = "Main"
$ListADGroup.AutoArrange = $true
$ListADGroup.GridLines = $true
$ListADGroup.MultiSelect = $false
$ListADGroup.View = "Details"
$ListADGroup.AutoSize = $true
#$ListADGroup.Columns[0].
$ListADGroup.Columns.Add("Groups")
$AllADGroups = Get-ADGroup -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Accounts,DC=domain,DC=internal' -SearchScope subtree -Properties Name | Sort-Object Name | foreach{[void]$ListADGroup.Items.Add($_.name)} 
$TSTAPP.controls.add($ListADGroup)

#== AD Users Listbox ==#
$ListADGroup2 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Listview
$ListADGroup2.Width = 356
$ListADGroup2.height = 220
$ListADGroup2.location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(370,22)
#$ListADGroup2.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$ListADGroup2.CheckBoxes = $true
$ListADGroup2.Name = "Main"
$ListADGroup2.AutoArrange = $true
$ListADGroup2.GridLines = $true
$ListADGroup2.MultiSelect = $false
$ListADGroup2.View = "Details"
$ListADGroup2.AutoSize = $true
#$ListADGroup2.Columns.Width = 100
$ListADGroup2.Columns.Add("Groups2")
$TSTAPP.controls.add($ListADGroup2)

#== Add Button ==#
$AddGroup               = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$AddGroup.text          = "Add"
$AddGroup.width         = 100
$AddGroup.height        = 30
$AddGroup.location      = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(265,249)
$AddGroup.Font          = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',10)
$TSTAPP.controls.add($AddGroup)
$AddGroup.Add_Click({

$itm = $ListADGroup.CheckedItems

foreach ($items in $itm){

$ListADGroup2.Items.Add($items.name)
}


})

$TSTAPP.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to debug using ISE or Visual Code you will see that the property containing the name is called `Text`

So replace :

```
$ListADGroup2.Items.Add($items.name)
```

by

```
$ListADGroup2.Items.Add($items.Text)
```

[image]